# Js check if key pressed is english i or turkish i

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

**The goal:**

with javascript/jquery capitalize (uppercase) the chars of the  as user types. 
For this we are using `$('#input').keypress(...)`

**The problem:**

In English, the letter `i` should be capitalized to `I`.

In Turkish, the letter `i` should be capitalized to `İ`.

If we get the input character from `.keypress()` we get the code corresponding to the char entered but we dont know if its the English `i` (to become `I`) or the Turkish `i` (to become `İ`).

If we get the input character from `.keydown()` we get the code corresponding to the key pressed but we cant get the char code (it's 0) to find out if the char pressed was the English `i` (to become `İ`) or the Turkish `ı` (to become `I`)

**The solution:**

So, as a workaround, we thought to use both `keydown()` and `keypress()` events and since `keydown()` comes first, to update a global variable with the `keydown()` code, which we check on `keypress()` to get both the key and the char to be able to work out which char to show.

*EDIT*: this only works on chrome!

**The question:**

Is that a viable, cross-platform solution ? Are we guaranteed that `keydown()` will always come first? Is there a better, less hacky solution to this problem?

*EDIT*

the solution I mention above only works on chrome, on firefox, the keypress code returned from english `i` and turkish `'` key (which both print `i`) is the same (73). Only chrome returns the correct code (222) for turkish `'`.

So, any solution that works in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, the order of the events is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the `toLocaleUpperCase()` method what you are looking for? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaleuppercase.asp - Turkish is explicitly mentioned!

Comment: the problem is I done know the locale the user has his keybord into.

Comment: for example if the user writes din (random example) and is on turkish language he expects to see DİN , if he is on english he expects DIN